# Deploying from Nexus to Tomcat (via Jenkins/Hudson)

Tags: tomcat, maven, hudson, jenkins, nexus

I am looking to create a three-step process for our internal development, and I am having some issues with the third step.

**Step 1:**
A developer will use Jenkins to build/deploy a snapshot release of a project to the Nexus snapshot repository.  As a post build step, this project will also deploy the built WAR to Tomcat (Using the DeployArtifact plugin).

**Step 2:**
Using the [Jenkins promoted builds plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin), a developer can nominate a build to be ready for QA.  This build is then tagged with an release candidate number, and deployed to the Nexus release repository.

**Step 3:**
I would like QA to be able to log into Jenkins and be able to deploy the newly created release candidate to Tomcat (a different tomcat instance for QA).

I know I can do all of this via a manual build process with shell scripting, but I was really hoping that there would be a Jenkins plugin to allow QA to find a list of the release candidate plugins and deploy a specific one to Tomcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like the Jenkins [Artifactory plug-in for release management](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plugin+-+Release+Management).

The closest you'll get, using Nexus, is the [Staging suite](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/staging.html) functionality. I'm not aware of any integration it might have with Hudson or Jenkins. Additionally this is only available with the professional version of Nexus.

Comment: After further research, your analysis seems spot on.  A little unfortunate, but that appears to be the state of things.

Comment: Thx. In practice it's not too bad. CI builds deploy to snapshot respositories, whereas release candidate builds are deployed to NexusPro. We then use the staging suite to manage the life-cycle of those release candidates, dropping them or promoting them dependent on our QA process.