# Deployment from Nexus to different environment (Test, Prerelease, Production)

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jenkins, nexus

I have Java projects built with maven, with artifacts (.jar .war) deployed to Nexus release repository. Also Jenkins is used for CI (building every hour) and automatically deploys to Tomcat (integration testing environment). We are using [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) for artifact deployment to Nexus, that is done on local PC.

I need to automate deploying to other 3 environments: Test, Prerelease, Production.

There are 2 problems:
It is unlikely that I can use Jenkins for that, as Jenkins can't know when current version is promoted as good & released.
The location of .jar .war is different after every release

```
http://nexusserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/company/projectname/component/0.2.4/
```

A bit similar questions is 
[Deploying from Nexus to Tomcat (via Jenkins/Hudson)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463488/deploying-from-nexus-to-tomcat-via-jenkins-hudson)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need what is often referred to as a "build pipeline" or "build pipeline manager" a term which I believe became popular with the (excellent) book "Continuous Delivery".

There is an open source Jenkins plugin called Build Pipeline Plugin that may meet your needs.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin

[image: Build Pipeline Manager plugin]